# elementary OS on a Lenovo M73 Tiny

Tags: lenovo

The Lenovo ThinkCentre M73 Tiny has a 2.6GHz Pentium Dual Core (G3220T), Intel HD Graphics, 8 GB ram, 3 MB cache, Intel H81 Express Chipset, HD Audio Realtexk ALC283, Intel Centrino Wireless N 2230 + Bluetooth.  320 GB HD.  Currently running Windows 10.  It's small...about the size of a Mac Mini or a Chromebox etc.  I can pick this up used in excellent condition for a shade over $100.  Would this machine be adequate for Elementary?  More than just adequate?   Thanks!

Comment: The Lenovo M73 Tiny is 64 bit.  I would ideally be installing Elementary from a disc via an external cd/dvd device. Probably setting the Lenovo up to (at least initially) dual boot into both Elementary and Windows 10.  And I am a total newbie to the world of linux and elementary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Elementary an a low-spec HP laptop, and it runs at least as well as it did under Win8 (which I hated), and probably better.

My laptop has an AMD e1-2100 dual-core CPU and 8GB of RAM

Below site compares the performance of the G3220T vs my e1-2100:

http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/235/AMD_E1-Series_E1-2100_vs_Intel_Pentium_Dual-Core_G3220T.html

As you can see, that Intel chip way outperforms my AMD, so I would say you'll have no issues at all running Elementary on that Lenovo, and the elelentary.io website lists [recommended specs](http://elementary.io/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) as

- 1 GHz 32-bit or 64-bit processor
- 1 GB of system memory (RAM)
- 15 GB of disk space
- Internet access

Give it a go - as long as you're careful when installing, so you don't wipe Windows 10 until you're sure you don't want it, you've got nothing to lose :)

Comment: Just as a follow-up.  I decided to go for a straight install of Elementary.  I was hard pressed to come up with a reason why I needed to keep Windows 10 on this machine.  I also have a MacMini in my office.  That would be my "other' computer.  So no Windows.  No dual boot issues.  Elementary installed quickly and painlessly.  So far great...am doing the updates adding applications.  Am liking it so far.  Thanks for your encouragement.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you did it, and that you're enjoying it :D

Comment: @DennyinOhio If this answer adequately answers your question, please mark it with the checkmark near the voting buttons.

Comment: Lewis...be glad to...but where are the voting buttons?